# CheckBox с кастомным текстом

Tags: android, html, текст, checkbox

Есть у меня элемент `CheckBox` который имеет атрибут `Text`. Я в `CheckBox` могу поместить только текст одного цвета и с откликом на клик только на весь текст а не наотдельные слова по отдельности и разные функции клика.

Например[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вы видите в `ConstrantLayout` довольно сложно выровнять элементы.
Мне нужно что бы желательно это было одним элементом как `CheckBox`

***Внимание вопрос***

1. Можно ли текст который на `CheckBox` заменит на HTML? Если **да** то можно ли сделать HTML кликабельным?
2. Можно как-то через код написать текст и сделать некоторые слова кликабельными + и задать етим же словам другой цвет?
3. Может есть кастомные другие виды таких CheckBOX которым можно задавать все выше описанные функции?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184597/how-do-i-make-a-portion-of-a-checkboxs-text-clickable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вот активность с полным описанием ответа на мой вопрос**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                //тут у меня организован ViewBinding на это не обращайте внимание
                            binding = ActivitySignUpBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
                            val view = binding.root
                            setContentView(view)
                            activity = this
                            viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
                    //Создаем переменную которая будет отвечать на отклик и на оформление нудного нам текста
                            val clickablePrivacy: ClickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
                                override fun onClick(p0: View) {
                                   // организовуве отзыв на клик
                                }
                                override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
                                    super.updateDrawState(ds)
                                    ds.isUnderlineText = true
                                    ds.color = getColor(R.color.button)
                               // задаем окраску и все стилевое оформление текста
                                }
                            }
        // для второго текста тоже нужно создать переменную с параметрами отзыва на отклик
                            val clickableTerm: ClickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
                                override fun onClick(p0: View) {
                                    p0.setOnClickListener { activity toast getString(R.string.term_of_service) }
                                }
                                override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
                                    super.updateDrawState(ds)
                                    ds.isUnderlineText = true
                                    ds.color = getColor(R.color.button)
                                }
                            }
                    //Создаем переменную которая будет переносить кнопку, оформление и добавляем в нее текст
                            val privacyPolicy = SpannableString(getString(R.string.privacy_policy))
    // в переменну добавляем параметры
                            privacyPolicy.setSpan(clickablePrivacy, 0, privacyPolicy.length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
                            val term = SpannableString(getString(R.string.term_of_service))
                            term.setSpan(clickableTerm, 0, term.length,  Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
                            val privacy = TextUtils.expandTemplate(getString(R.string.privacy) +" ^1 ,\nand "+ "^2", privacyPolicy, term)
                    // засуваем в CheckBox обработаный весь текст
                            binding.cbRememder.text = privacy
                        }
```